# Font width wrong in terminals

Tags: command-line, kubuntu, kde, fonts

I upgraded one of my machines from Kubuntu 16.04 to 16.10. Now I have an issue in all my terminals that run inside KDE (so Konsole and Yakuake but not tty2).

These terminals seem to have a mismatching idea of the character width of the text to what the actual with is. So if I type a bunch of "w", after a number of characters, the last ones I typed are not visible until I type some more. Conversely, if I type some "i", the caret will be way to the right of the last character, making it look like there are a bunch of spaces following it.

[image]

In this image you can also see that the "0" at the end of hostname is cut off.

I had a look through the settings of my terminal though did not find anything that seemed relevant. Changing the appearance type did not fix the issue, and neither did changing my systems monospace font from "Oxygen Mono 9" to "Ubuntu Mono".

Any idea on what might be causing this or how to further debug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently my dist upgrade did not fully finish. I had run `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`, neither of which fixed the issue. What ended up doing so is `apt full-upgrade`.